# Strange behavior of a forEach on an array NodeJS/Cron

Tags: javascript, arrays, node.js, string

I'm having trouble with the array `groups_to_check`, working with a Redis client (NodeJS).

I create the variable `groups_to_check`, and push data into it only if it doesn't exist.

This data comes from `data2`, which is an item of `data1.forEach`

Example of `data2` value : `group:12:myGroupName:myChannelName:messages`

```
cron.schedule('*/2 * * * * *', function()  {
console.log('running every 2 seconds');

var groups_to_check = [];

client.keys('group:*', function (error, data1) {
    data1.forEach(function(data2){

        var temp_key_group  = data2;
        temp_key_group      = temp_key_group.split(':');

        if(typeof groups_to_check[temp_key_group[1]] === 'undefined'){
            groups_to_check[temp_key_group[1]] = "_"+temp_key_group[1];
            console.log("_"+temp_key_group[1]);
        }

    });

    console.log( "____ "+ groups_to_check );
});
```

});

`console.log` shows that my array is has empty items :

```
running every 2 seconds
_12
_13
_1
_11
_21
____ ,_1,,,,,,,,,,_11,_12,_13,,,,,,,,_21
```

What would be the cause of having empty items in the last console.log ?
Thank you.

Comment: Well obviously if you have only the items `12`, `13`, `1`, `11`, and `21`, then only those get set in the array. What else did you expect your code to do?

Comment: Actually this is how it's supposed to go, but as you see, the last console.log shows the final content of groups_to_check, and it has multiple empty items.
How could it set empty items of the first console.log never shows empty content ?

Comment: Perhaps calling the if actually adds empty data ?

Comment: What do you want to go in there instead of the empty items? Or do you want no empty items at all?

Comment: You're explicitly creating a (sort-of) sparse array. You don't log anything when you don't add to the array. Not sure what the confusion is.

Comment: I don't want empty items at all, ideally we should have :
___ 1,11,12,13,21.
I'm wondering if calling if actually creates the new key in the array. If that is the case, I don't how how to check for an existing key without adding an empty one.

Comment: @Mr.Miel Push onto the array instead of setting it in a specific numeric location. Or don't index with numbers, use strings. Or... etc. Many solutions, depending on what you actually need, which we don't know.

Comment: @DaveNewton Thank you, I'll try and be back to let you know !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a way to my problem by changing groups_to_chek from [] to {}.
Thank you for your time !